# odoo allow existing user to signup using google login

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, google-signin

I am trying to integrate a google login with my odoo website, I was successful in logging in new users but I was not able to login using existing user can anyone guide me if i had done anything wrong.
From the comments i am trying to include what i have done so far to trace down the issue.

1. I was able to setup login using google.
2. I was not able to login using google using existing user so after extensive search i found a solution like we need to send a reset password from settings for a existing user and it will work in-order to to make the google login work and I worked like charm but i don't know whether it is the perfect solution for the issue

Comment: Your second point should be posted as answer, because at least it is a solution ;-) Maybe others have other solutions ;-)

Comment: you know why it is that way working